# why reflect.TypeOf(new(Encoder)).Elem() != reflect.TypeOf(interfaceVariable)?

Tags: go, reflection

Here's the short test:

```
type Encoder interface {
    Encode()
}
func main() {
    encoderInterface1 := reflect.TypeOf(new(Encoder)).Elem()
    var en Encoder
    encoderInterface2 := reflect.TypeOf(en)
    fmt.Println(encoderInterface1 == encoderInterface2)
}
```

Outputs `false`.

Why is it `false`? I was expecting it to be `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [reflect.TypeOf](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#TypeOf) docs:

> TypeOf returns the reflection Type that represents the dynamic type of
> i. **If i is a nil interface value, TypeOf returns nil.**

Therefore:

```
var en Encoder // nil interface value

encoderInterface2 := reflect.TypeOf(en) // <- nil
```

As for:

```
encoderInterface1 := reflect.TypeOf(new(Encoder)).Elem()
```

breaking this into two parts:

```
pi := reflect.TypeOf(new(Encoder)) // <- this is a pointer to an interface (so not nil)
encoderInterface1 := pi.Elem()
```

So:

```
encoderInterface1 != encoderInterface2
```

because:

```
encoderInterface1 != nil
```

Comment: Yeah this will obviously be `true`, but why wasn't the old version `true`?